# Disable mouse support for Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, arch-linux, input-device

How does one disable all mouse support on Linux? Be it USB mouse, be it PS mouse, how does one make all of the connected mouse devices to be disabled?

I'm working on a surveillance camera monitoring system, and I've been assigned to prevent end-users to hook up mouse and control the environment.

I'm running X, and that's where I have to disable the mouse.

I've already seen:

- http://wpkg.org/Disable_/_enable_keyboard_and_mouse_in_Linux
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/disable-mouse-not-touchpad-in-xorg-while-idle

But both seem to be manual, explicitly disabling a mouse by model or id.

Comment: `rmmod evdev`??

Comment: > "prevent end-users to hook up mouse" - just turn off power of USB

Comment: http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/topic/33712-disable-mouse/#entry211183

Comment: Ended up implementing a solution based on what @Nykakin posted. Mind making an answer out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script which disables mouse devices which I posted in comments: http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/topic/33712-disable-mouse/#entry211183

It's based on `xinput` utility and in your case you need to disable this tool as well to prevent users from enabling mouse again. The simplest way is modification of binary permissions:

```
# chmod o-x /usr/bin/xinput
```